# Patching the properties of a children entity. How to correctly map the entity to execute the patch method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a patch method in my ClientUserController but the patchDoc is not updating the properties of the User entity which is a child of ClientUser entity. The Post method is working fine and it's updating every child property of the ClientUser entity which I have mapped. However, for some reason this is not working for the PATCH method.

**User**

```
public int Id { get; set; }

    public Genders Gender { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public City City { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
```

**ClientUser**
public int Id { get; set; }

```
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
```

**ClientUserController (simple)**

```
[HttpPatch("{id}", Name = "PatchClientUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchClientUser(int clientId, int id,
        [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<ClientUserForUpdateDto> patchDoc)
    {
        if (patchDoc == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var clientUserFromRepo = await _clientUserRepository.GetClientUserByIdAsync(clientId, id);

        if (clientUserFromRepo == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Client User Not Found");
        }

        var clientUserToPatch = Mapper.Map<ClientUserForUpdateDto>(clientUserFromRepo);

        patchDoc.ApplyTo(clientUserToPatch);

        Mapper.Map(clientUserToPatch, clientUserFromRepo);

        _clientUserRepository.UpdateEntity(clientUserFromRepo);

        await _clientUserRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

**ClientUserProfile**

```
public class ClientUserProfile : Profile
    {
        public ClientUserProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ClientUser, ClientUserDto>();
            CreateMap<ClientUserForCreationDto, ClientUser>();
            CreateMap<ClientUser, ClientUserForUpdateDto>(MemberList.Destination);
            CreateMap<ClientUserForUpdateDto, ClientUser>(MemberList.Source);
        }
```

**UserProfile**

```
public class UserProfile : Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
        CreateMap<UserForCreationDto, User>();
        CreateMap<User, UserForUpdateDto>(MemberList.Destination);
        CreateMap<UserForUpdateDto, User>(MemberList.Source);
    }
}
```

The POST method as well as the GET method for a ClientUser is working properly.

My ClientUserForUpdateDto looks as follow:

```
public string UserFirstname { get; set; }
    public string UserLastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
```

in my requestBody from postman I have the following:

```
[
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/userLastname",
    "value": "Some lastname"
}
```

]

Which would be the way to go if I want to change the LastName of a clientUser by its Id and map it correctly.

In Postman as a response I get the correct NoContent response. However, the ClientUser is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem should be in the following code line :

```
Mapper.Map(clientUserToPatch, clientUserFromRepo);
```

You could add the following code in your ClientUserProfile :

```
CreateMap<ClientUserForUpdateDto, ClientUser>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.User , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
CreateMap<ClientUserForUpdateDto, User>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserLastname))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserFirstname));
```